# how to unit test onBeforeRouteUpdate in vue 3 with jest

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-router, vue-composition-api, vue-test-utils

i have a case where the global component using `onBeforeRouteUpdate` from Vue router,

here is the code

```
setup() {

    const doSomething = (): boolean => {
      if (active.value) {
        emit('close')
        return false
      }

      return true
    }

    onBeforeRouteLeave(doSomething)
}
```

I have tried to mock the lifecycle router like this

```
jest.mock('vue-router', () => ({
  onBeforeRouteLeave: jest.fn(),
  onBeforeRouteUpdate: jest.fn(),
}))
```

but the function on `doSomething` doesn't test / uncovered, how correction to test that onBeforeRouteLeave with that function `doSomething` to be test?